# ngFor is not working in Html file , data from server is not displayed

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-directive

I am working in angular 8 , 
I am trying to iterate data with *ngFor but it is not iteration It's value in the view

I am sharing my code

html

```
  <div *ngFor='let data of attendanceInput ; let i = index'>
    <p> {{data.emp_name}}</p>
    <p> {{i}} </p>
    </div>
```

.ts file

```
updateAttendance() {


    let page  = "3";
    let role = 'rs';
    let id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
    let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    let dates: any;

    this.restData.weeklyAttendanceUpdate(id, token, this.role , page).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result['messagecode'] == 200) {
        this.attendanceInput = result['data'];
        console.log(this.attendanceInput);
        console.log(this.attendanceInput.length);
      }

    });
  }
```

In console I am getting value of attendanceInput & attendanceInput.length  , but data is not displaying in the HTML

Comment: Post your error/exception!!!

Comment: can you post the result of console.log?

Answer (score 0):

I filled attendanceInput with  test data, there is no problem:

```
attendanceInput = [{ emp_name: 'a' }, { emp_name: 'b' }];
```

Result:
a
0
b
1

Make sure that the data you put in **attendanceInput**  is in an array form.And also check that **emp_name** is match with your object's property.